# How to implement flood fill in scala with return type List

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the flood fill algorithm in Scala, in a functional way, such that I won't have to use variables or state of any kind.

So what I'm asking for is the implementation, for a function definition similar to this, where the return type is a list of the pixels to be filled.

```
def FloodFill(replacementColor: Color, pixel: Pixel, pixels: List[Pixels] ): List[Pixels]
```

`pixels: List[Pixel` is assumed to be the border of the shape and `pixel: Pixel` to be somewhere within the shape.

So far I've tried something like this:

```
def FloodFill(replacementColor: Color, pixel: Pixel, pixels: List[Pixels] ): List[Pixels]= {
  if(pixels.exists(p => p.x == pixel.x && p.y == pixel.y)) return pixels
  FloodFill(color, new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y-1, color), new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y, color) ::pixels)
  FloodFill(color, new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y+1, color), new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y, color) ::pixels)
  FloodFill(color, new Pixel(pixel.x-1, pixel.y, color), new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y, color) ::pixels)
  FloodFill(color, new Pixel(pixel.x+1, pixel.y, color), new Pixel(pixel.x, pixel.y, color) ::pixels)
}
```

... which clearly doesn't work.

Comment: If it returns "a list of the pixels to be filled" then what purpose does `replacementColor` serve? Your failed attempt doesn't use it. Is the returned `List` supposed to be in a specific order? Does it have to be a `List` or will a `Set` do?

Comment: The returned list need to be a specefic color yes. And I'm not quite sure that a  `set` will do, but if you have a solution with `set` I would very much like to see it.